# Why is this function returning a function?

Tags: javascript

Why am I assigning counter function to count variable? And what is the purpose?

```js
function counter() {
  var localVar = 0;
  return function() {
    localVar++;
    return localVar;
  }
}

  var count = counter(); // I am confused here.

  console.log(count());
```

Comment: A better name for `counter()` would be `generateCounter()`.  However, this is just a really bad example of closures in JS.  If you want to understand what that function does, look into closures.  There are more appropriate examples out there than this one.  One good application is callbacks.

Answer (score 4):

`counter` is a function-factory, it returns a function when called.

By assigning a variable to `counter` you can keep track of this counter and every time you call it the variable `localVar` will get incremented by one, if you were to always call `counter()()` you couldn't keep track of that value.

Example:

```js
function counter() {
  var localVar = 0;
  return function() {
    localVar++;
    return localVar;
  }
}

var count = counter(); 

for(var i = 0; i<99; i++) count();

console.log(count()); // 100



for(var i = 0; i<99; i++) counter()();

console.log(counter()()); // 1
```

Comment: So in order to keep track of the data in the function I am assigning the function to the count variable?

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MuhammadNuhel If you feel Luca's answer helped you, please remember to accept his answer. He'll get a bit of cred for his contribution and future readers of this page will know which answer was most helpful. Everybody wins.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't assigning the `counter` function to a variable, you're calling `counter` and assigning what it returns to the variable.

It's just that `counter` *returns another function*.

Note inside `counter`, there's the bit:

```
return function() {
  localVar++;
  return localVar;
}
```

Which can literally be read as "return a function that increments a local variable, then returns the current state of that variable".

Comment: Okay, then why can't I write console.log(count)? I have to write console.log(count());

Comment: @MuhammadNuhel Because `count` is a function that you need to call to get a number. `count` is what `counter` returns, and `counter` returns a function.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried console.log(count); and the output was [Function]. But when I tried console.log(count()); I got the number.

Comment: @MuhammadNuhel Yes, because `count` is a function, and that's what you see when you print a function. You need to call it (add the `()`) to get numbers out of it

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is you can use a `counter` on whatever variable you assign it to so you can keep multiple instances that all keep track independent of one another.

See example below:

```js
function counter() {
  var localVar = 0;
  return function() {
    localVar++;
    return localVar;
  }
}

  var count = counter(); 
  var secCount = counter();

  console.log(`count: ${count()}`);
  console.log(`count: ${count()}`);
  console.log(`secCount: ${secCount()}`);
  console.log(`secCount: ${secCount()}`);
  console.log(`count: ${count()}`);
  console.log(`count: ${count()}`);
  console.log(`secCount: ${secCount()}`);
  console.log(`secCount: ${secCount()}`);
  console.log(`count: ${count()}`);
```

Comment: @MuhammadNuhel Did any of these answers help clear things up?

Answer (score 0):

The function `counter` is a function factory, which is a function that returns a new function—which, in this case, is a function that increments a value.

This new function is then assigned to the variable `count`.

The usefulness of this pattern is that functions have access to their local [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description). So, that function can access and increment the variable `localVar` in its scope—which is also declared when `counter` is called—, and no outside functions can modify it, so there are no conflicts of multiple functions changing the same variable. Also, this way you can have multiple `counters` that don't conflict with each other.